# What is imagebase word means used in Lena151 RE tutorial?

Tags: pe

In part 3 of lena RE tutorial, i see a word : imagebase

Can anyone tell me more about this and better meaning of this word?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format):

> The preferred address of the first byte of image when loaded into memory [...] The default for DLLs is 0x10000000.
> [...] The default for Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows 95, Windows 98, and Windows Me is 0x00400000

So, in case of exe, you can usually expect that it will be loaded at `0x400000` address and when you load the dll, it is loaded at `0x10000000` by default. All these values correspond only to particular process' virtual memory.

PE files may have different image bases than the default ones. So if a dll has `ImageBase = 0x20000000`, you can expect it to be loaded at this address instead. Note however, that it is only the *preferred* address - it may be changed if, for example, second dll that is loaded into the same process already occupies this space.

If you have any more doubts regarding PE format, you can either follow the docs linked above or slightly more compact description [here](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PE-Portable-executable).

Comment: Nice, Thank you for Complete explanations.  But what is image bases means? My English is weak. i don't know What is the meaning of this word. What does it refer to?

Comment: It's just the address where the first byte of PE file is loaded into memory when the process is started.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does this word have another synonym? (imagebase) I know this word only means photo. My English is weak

Comment: “ImageBase” is just a name of a member of a structure (‘OptionalHeader’ to be precise). It consists of two words: image and base. The word “image” here refers to the executable loaded into memory.

Comment: well when windows loads a file into memory it creates a map or in other words an image of the file the base address where it started mapping is the image base address  like the fourth photo on the wall from left side is photo of my xyz like wise

Comment: Thank you very much dear blabb and bart1e.